# Using Horner's method to find $P(x)$ and $P'(x)$

Tags: numerical-methods

This is one of those questions that straddle programming and math.

I'm struggling with Horner's method for solving $P(x)$ and $P(x)$ as the same time. My textbook gives the algorithm as

```
P(x) = a_n x n + a_n−1 x n−1 + ··· + a_1 x + a_0 = (x−x0)Q(x) + b0

INPUT degree n; coefficients a_0 , a_1 , . . . , a_n ; x0 .
OUTPUT y = P(x 0 ); z = P (x 0 ).
Step 1 Set y = a_n ; (Compute b n for P.)
           z = a_n . (Compute b n−1 for Q.)
Step 2 For j = n − 1, n − 2, . . . , 1
           set y = x0 * y + a_j ; (Compute b_j for P.)
                   z = x0 * z + y. (Compute b_j−1 for Q.)
Step 3 Set y = x0 + y + a_0 .
Step 4 OUTPUT (y, z);
       STOP.
```

But even though the input states it wants the coefficients it seems that I have to enter the constant as well to obtain the correct answer.

Here is the link to my stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267427/using-horners-method-to-find-px-and-px?noredirect=1#comment44891674_28267427

So my question is: For Horner's method, is the constant considered a coefficient Since $c = cx^0$?

Comment: In step 3 shouldn't it just be $y=y + a_0$ (and why is this needed, couldn't you just extend step 2 to $j=0$?).

Comment: What do you mean by "the constant"? Do you mean $a_0$?

Comment: @mathmandan yes $a_0$

Comment: OK good. Then I'm not quite sure what you're confused about: it says right in the description of the algorithm that $a_0$ is considered a coefficient, and that it is part of the input into the algorithm.  (Note: mathematicians would also consider "the constant term" of a polynomial to be one of the coefficients of that polynomial. The idea is that a polynomial is just made up of its coefficients...it would be awkward to have to say "the polynomial's coefficients along with its constant term" all the time.)  Or have I still misunderstood your question?

Comment: @mathmandan I eventually figured that out. Maybe I should take a basic reading course along with maths :D